# How to make TreeStructureProvider updatable on actionPerformed method?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I have a code, provided by example. I want PsiFileNode to change its color on click on my implemented action.

```
 <extensions defaultExtensionNs="com.intellij">
        <treeStructureProvider implementation="ru.softmg.highlighter.CustomTreeStructureProvider" />
      </extensions>
```

This is TreeStructureProvider

```
package ru.softmg.highlighter;

import com.intellij.ide.projectView.TreeStructureProvider;
import com.intellij.ide.projectView.ViewSettings;
import com.intellij.ide.projectView.impl.nodes.PsiFileNode;
import com.intellij.ide.util.treeView.AbstractTreeNode;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.Project;
import com.intellij.openapi.project.ProjectManager;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomTreeStructureProvider implements TreeStructureProvider {
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Collection<AbstractTreeNode> modify(@NotNull AbstractTreeNode parent, @NotNull Collection<AbstractTreeNode> children, ViewSettings settings) {
        Project project = ProjectManager.getInstance().getOpenProjects()[0];
        ArrayList<AbstractTreeNode> nodes = new ArrayList<>();
        for(AbstractTreeNode child : children) {
            if(child instanceof PsiFileNode) {
                PsiFileNode psiFileNode = (PsiFileNode) child;
                CustomPsiFileNode customPsiFileNode = new CustomPsiFileNode(project, psiFileNode.getValue(), psiFileNode.getSettings());
                nodes.add(customPsiFileNode);
            }
            else {
                nodes.add(child);
            }
        }
        return nodes;
    }
}
```

And this is my action

```
public class ProjectHighlighter extends AnAction {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(AnActionEvent anActionEvent) {

    }
}
```

What should I do for TreeStructureProvider updating on calling actionPerformed method?

Comment: Which PsiFileNode do you need to change the color for?

Comment: @yole I need to select group of files, perform my action, registered in context menu and change background color of all files in group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
AbstractProjectViewPane currentProjectViewPane = ProjectView.getInstance(project).getCurrentProjectViewPane();
if (currentProjectViewPane != null) {
  for (PsiFileSystemItem item : myFileGroup) {
    currentProjectViewPane.updateFrom(item, false, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: It works, but the problem is how should I detect who called the modify() method in CustomTreeStructureProvider. It called several times while startup of IDEA, and it should be called when I perform my action from UI. What should I do to detect whenever modify() is calling by default or by user input?

Comment: You don't need to detect that. You need to have a component storing the list of files that need to be colored, and apply the colors based on the stored state in every call to modify().